# Proper way to register apps in Django

Tags: django

I noticed different ways to register apps in django project. 
For example, if I have an app called Catalog, in settings.py I can use either just the name of the app 'catalog' or the longer name 'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig'. 
What is the difference and which one is more accurate way to register an app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You (app user) should only care about app's name:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rock_n_roll',
    ...
)
```

This is because app author subclasses `AppConfig` to configure and provide proper name for their app:

```
# rock_n_roll/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class RockNRollConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'rock_n_roll'
    verbose_name = "Rock ’n’ roll"
```

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/):

> That will cause `RockNRollConfig` to be used when `INSTALLED_APPS` just contains `rock_n_roll`. This allows you to make use of `AppConfig` features without requiring your users to update their `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Besides this use case, it’s best to avoid using `default_app_config` and instead specify the app config class in `INSTALLED_APPS` as described next.

Why use `AppConfig` at all?

> It is important to understand that a Django application is just a set of code that interacts with various parts of the framework. There’s no such thing as an Application object. However, there’s a few places where Django needs to interact with installed applications, mainly for configuration and also for introspection. That’s why the application registry maintains metadata in an `AppConfig` instance for each installed application.

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose you generated the app named todos the it should be written as:-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'todos.apps.TodosConfig',
...
]
```

Comment: I found out (after using django-tenants) that writing the full path (including .apps.TodosConfig) might actually produce unwanted results.
It seems to work, until it does not: https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/issues/577

The difficulty is, of course, that the Django documentation writes that both options are fine (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/).